# How to create this condition in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, slideshow, conditional-statements

I want to make a jQuery code that does this:

If an element with class `'slide1', 'slide2' or 'slide3'` has also class `"on"`, then find an element with class `'slide-1', 'slide-2' or 'slide-3'` change its opacity to `1` and change opacity of others to `0`.

***Note:** Element 'slide1' is "paired" with 'slide-1', etc. So if 'slide1' has class "on", 'slide-1' should have opacity set to 1 and 'slide-2' and 'slide-3' should have opacity set to 0.*

Elements 'slide1, ...' are radio buttons for the slideshow:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slider-radio-buttons">
  <div class="on slide1"></div>
  <div class="off slide2"></div>
  <div class="off slide3"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".slider-radio-buttons").on('click', '.off', function() {
    $(".on").removeClass('on').toggleClass('off');
    $(this).toggleClass('on').removeClass('off');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/5/

**IMPORTANT:** Radio buttons are working great, I just need to pair them with slides in slideshow (slide-1, ...) and set opacity of the one, that is turned on, to 1.

Comment: That seems like a really complicated way to do something inherantly simple ?

Comment: @user2753573 As per my understanding your code is working.. See this link : http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/35/

Comment: I'm open for any simple solution. I just need to pair radio buttons with slides in slideshow (slide-1, ...) and set opacity of the one, that is turned on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var buttons = $(".slider-radio-buttons div"),
    slides  = $('[class^="slide-"]');

buttons.on('click', function () {
    buttons.not(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $(this).addClass('on').removeClass('off');

    var n = this.className.replace('on','').trim().slice(-1);

    var slide = slides.filter(function() {
        return this.className.slice(-1) == n;
    });

    slides.not(slide).hide();
    slide.show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/36/)

Comment: This is it! I've just replaced `.hide()` `.show()` with `.animate()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .hasClass( "foo" ) and not( ".classname" ) functions in jquery

Answer (score 1):

This is another way if you would like to try... ***[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/49/)***

HTML...

```
<div class="slider-radio-buttons">
  <div id="slide-1" class="on"></div>
  <div id="slide-2" class="off"></div>
  <div id="slide-3" class="off"></div>
</div>

<div class="slides">
    <div class="slide-1">Slide-1</div>
    <div class="slide-2">Slide-2</div>
    <div class="slide-3">Slide-3</div>
</div>
```

JQuery...

```
$(".slider-radio-buttons").on('click', '.off', function() {
        $(".on").removeClass('on').toggleClass('off');
        $(this).toggleClass('on').removeClass('off');
    $("div[class^='slide-']").css('display','none');

    $('.'+this.id).css('display','block');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If i can understand your answers the solution is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/30/

```
<div class="slider-radio-buttons">
   <div class="off"></div>
   <div class="off"></div>
   <div class="off"></div>
</div>

$(".slider-radio-buttons div").first().addClass('on');

$(".slider-radio-buttons div").on('click', function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on'))
    {
       $('.on').removeClass('on');
       $(this).addClass('on');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses index position of a pressed radio button to choose the appropriate slider

HTML

```
<div class="slider-radio-buttons">
  <div class="slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide3"></div>
</div>

<div class="slide-1">slide 1</div>
<div class="slide-2">slide 2</div>
<div class="slide-3">slide 3</div>
```

js

```
   var radios = $(".slider-radio-buttons div");

   function setActive(i) {
         radios.removeClass("on").addClass("off").
         eq(i).addClass("on").removeClass("off");

         $("[class^=slide-]").hide().eq(i).show();
   }

  setActive(0);
  radios.on('click',function() { setActive($(this).index()) });
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/50/)